# Pull multiple rows from one table but only one row from a related table

Tags: mysql, pdo

I currently am trying to join two tables but prevent duplication of information from one of the tables.

The user's table has 4 columns, uid, name, email and status.
The stats table has 4 columns, uid, date, follows, views

What I would like to be able to do is pull every record from the stats table and only the name, email and status values from the user table. The issue I have with the below SQL is that it duplicates the data from the user table, is there a way around this?

```
SELECT u.name
     , u.email
     , u.status
     , s.date
     , s.follows
     , s.views 
  FROM users u
  JOIN stats s 
    ON u.id = s.uid 
 WHERE name = :name
```

Comment: If there are multiple records per user in the stats table, then I'm afraid, sql will join the details from the user table to each of the records, there is nothing you can do about it apart from querying the two tables separately.

Comment: Seems like this is covered above and below but , for further assistance, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want every matching stats row to be accompanied by its matching users row, then you have to run two queries:

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, u.email, u.status FROM users u WHERE name = :name
```

Note the result of `u.id` because you'll use it as a parameter for the second query:

```
SELECT s.date, s.follows, s.views FROM stats s WHERE s.uid = :uid
```

You have to understand that the relational model works *because* every query result is itself a relation. The matching data is returned in every row, and this is what allows `JOIN` to be part of an algebra, where the result can be used as the operand of another `JOIN`, or a `GROUP BY`, or some other relational operation.

You should read [SQL and Relational Theory: How to Write Accurate SQL Code](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022879.do) by C. J. Date.